# Changing BorderColor from Button like TextColor when it's enabled/disabled

Tags: ios, xamarin, uibutton, xamarin.ios, uicolor

If my TextField is empty, the button should be disabled and the textColor and borderColor from the button should be gray. But when the button is enabled the colors should be blue for example.

Changing the textColor is easy:

```
button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
button.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Gray, UIControlState.Disabled);
```

But how can I change the color from the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ViewDidLoad ()` method of your `ViewController`:

```
MyButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
MyButton.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Gray, UIControlState.Disabled);
MyButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
MyButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 2;
UpdateButton();
MyEntryField.AllEditingEvents += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    UpdateButton();
};
```

Update Method:

```
public void UpdateButton() {
    if (MyEntryField.HasText) {
        MyButton.Enabled = false;
        MyButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
    } else {
        MyButton.Enabled = true;
        MyButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
    }
}
```

Disabled:

[image]

Enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
 var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.System); // New type in iOS 7
  button.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
  button.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
  button.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with KeyValueObserving (KVO) too like so:

```
    IntPtr tokenObserveButtonEnabled = (IntPtr) 1;
    UIButton button;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var textf = new UITextField (new CGRect (150, 150, 50, 50));

        button = new UIButton (new CGRect (50, 50, 50, 50));
        button.SetTitle ("TEST", UIControlState.Normal);
        button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
        button.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Gray, UIControlState.Disabled);
        button.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        button.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
        button.AddObserver (this, (NSString)"enabled",
            NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, tokenObserveButtonEnabled);

        Add (button);
        Add (textf);
        textf.AllEditingEvents += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
            var tf = sender as UITextField;
            button.Enabled = tf.HasText;
        };
    }

    public override void ObserveValue (NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr ctx)
    {
        if (ctx == tokenObserveButtonEnabled) {
            button.Layer.BorderColor = button.Enabled ? UIColor.Black.CGColor : UIColor.Gray.CGColor ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: TBH just wanted to see if it could be done this way, i've not done much KVO in Xamarin

Comment: Cool, never really seen it done in C#. I usually run to the closest bar when KVO is mentioned, years ago I inherited a project at had close to a thousand active observers (pre-ARC), just insane coding :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIButton sampleButton;

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        sampleButton = new UIButton (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (10f, 100f, 300f, 50f));
        this.sampleButton.SetTitle ("Sample Button", UIControlState.Normal);
        this.sampleButton.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
        this.sampleButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 3;
        this.sampleButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 3;
        this.sampleButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
        this.sampleButton.TouchUpInside += sampleButtonClicked;
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
        this.View.AddSubview (sampleButton);        
    }

    private void sampleButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Make this variable change and boarder color being managed by a switch loop
        var selectColorCode = 1;

        switch (selectColorCode) {

            case 0:
                this.sampleButton.Enabled = false;
                this.sampleButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Brown.CGColor;
                break;

            case 1:
                this.sampleButton.Enabled = true;
                this.sampleButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```